# Including a Float on a Separate Page

Tags: floats, positioning, page-breaking

I am having difficulty positioning a float (table) in latex. I have two paragraphs of text, and I want the float to be inbetween these two sections of text, but I also want the table to be on a new page.

I am after:

- Page 1 first paragraph
- Page 2 table
- Page 3 second paragraph

I have been using:

```
\documentclass[reqno, a4paper,12pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{fullpage} 

\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

This is just some example text that should be on the page \emph{before} the figure. This is just some example text that should be on the page \emph{before} the figure. This is just some example text that should be on the page \emph{before} the figure. This is just some example text that should be on the page \emph{before} the figure. This is just some example text that should be on the page \emph{before} the figure. This is just some example text that should be on the page \emph{before} the figure. This is just some example text that should be on the page \emph{before} the figure. This is just some example text that should be on the page \emph{before} the figure. This is just some example text that should be on the page \emph{before} the figure. This is just some example text that should be on the page \emph{before} the figure. This is just some example text that should be on the page \emph{before} the figure. This is just some example text that should be on the page \emph{before} the figure. This is just some example text that should be on the page \emph{before} the figure. This is just some example text that should be on the page \emph{before} the figure. This is just some example text that should be on the page \emph{before} the figure. This is just some example text that should be on the page \emph{before} the figure. This is just some example text that should be on the page \emph{before} the figure. This is just some example text that should be on the page \emph{before} the figure. This is just some example text that should be on the page \emph{before} the figure. This is just some example text that should be on the page \emph{before} the figure. This is just some example text that should be on the page \emph{before} the figure. This is just some example text that should be on the page \emph{before} the figure. This is just some example text that should be on the page \emph{before} the figure. This is just some example text that should be on the page \emph{before} the figure. This is just some example text that should be on the page \emph{before} the figure. This is just some example text that should be on the page \emph{before} the figure. This is just some example text that should be on the page \emph{before} the figure. This is just some example text that should be on the page \emph{before} the figure. This is just some example text that should be on the page \emph{before} the figure. This is just some example text that should be on the page \emph{before} the figure.



\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Table 1}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{P{48mm}P{48mm}P{48mm}}
\includegraphics[width=3cm]  & \includegraphics[width=3cm]  & \includegraphics[width=3cm] k  \\
\includegraphics[width=3cm] & \includegraphics[width=3cm] & \includegraphics[width=3cm] k \\
\includegraphics[width=3cm] & \includegraphics[width=3cm] & \includegraphics[width=3cm] k \\
\includegraphics[width=3cm] & \includegraphics[width=3cm] & \includegraphics[width=3cm]  k \\
\includegraphics[width=3cm] & \includegraphics[width=3cm] & \includegraphics[width=3cm] k\\
V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V   && \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}




I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page. I want this text to be on a new page.

\end{document}
```

I decided to type in the letter 'V' multiple times at the bottom of my table to try and push the text below it onto a new page (I would then phantom the V's) but as soon as you get to a certain number of v's, the table immeditely moves to the very last page. It's almost like some of the page is reserved for text and some images. If there would be a way to make it that if over 60% of the table is float then don't include any text then that would be ideal. I did experiment with the `\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{.8}%` command with no success. I had some success with `\clearpage` but this seems to only work if you're not including any figures after the command. I do plan on including figures after this section. I am asking for a solution that only affects these 3 pages. Or at least a way to amend the percentage of float allowed on page (so I can at least force it by adding V's to the bottom of the page).

Sorry for the long explanation. I hope you guys can assist!

Comment: Put `\clearpage` before and after the table.

Comment: Or even better, use `[p]`. Or don't use a float if you don't want the table to float.

Comment: by using `h` you are explicitly specifying that the float can _not_ go on a float page that just contains floats and no text.

Comment: I can not guess what you mean by `I had some success with \clearpage but this seems to only work if you're not including any figures after the command` If you use `\clearpage` then has no effect on floats that come after that point.

Comment: Excellent! I didn't realise I needed to put `\clearpage` before and after the text. Perfect, thanks for the help! It's a shame that I cannot mark your response @Johannes_B as an answer.